# Apache URL point to root

Tags: apache, url, routes, virtualhost

Is it possible to route any URL in apache to always point to DocumentRoot in my VirtualHost?

So that f.ex: `/foo/bar/` will always request `/`.

I’m thinking something like (excuse my newbie pseudo-code):

```
AliasMatch ^/.* DocumentRoot
```

Comment: Have you tried redirecting using htaccess, huh?

Comment: Not interested in a redirect, I want the server to always serve the document root regardless of URL path in the browser.

Comment: You need to use Rewrite engine ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine). Apache has one: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Bo Ok, got that. DO you have a simple example you can post as an answer? Pointing to the apache docs is only semi-helpful as I have very little Apache experience.

Comment: @David: Here is several examples that can help you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html more specifically example "Moved DocumentRoot"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following seems to be the pattern most CMSs use.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```